# Defining a Tensor

Tags: category-theory, tensor-products, tensors

So, I've been trying to look into some basic, yet mathematical, definitions of a tensor.

In that sense, there's one that particularly caught my attention. It goes as follows: Let $U,V,W$ be vector spaces, and consider the bilinear mapping:
\begin{equation}\varphi:U\times V\to W\end{equation}
Such that $|W|^{|U\times V|}$ is also a vector space, the one accounting all of the bilinear maps from $U\times V$ to $W$. Supposing another random vector space $Z$, if we define a **linear** mapping:
\begin{equation}\bar h:W\to Z\end{equation}
We can note that bilinear maps on $Z$ can be obtained through composition of a bilinear function with $\bar h$, so,accounting for all $|W|^{|U\times V|}$ mappings, we can form bilinear forms on $Z$. Staying on small categories allows us to let the morphisms be the bilinear functions we're mapping, and the objects to be our vector spaces. By doing so, we can note that this defines a functor. By making the diagram:
\begin{equation}U\times V\xrightarrow{\varphi}W\xrightarrow{\bar h}Z\end{equation}

And recalling that our construction defined a functor, we can define the tensor product to be our object, which is, for the way we defined the categories, a vector space, which will allow an universal morphism to the functor, with the respective universal property for our mappings. That is, a vector space which allows us to construct the bilinear mappings on $Z$ by inducing the same functor that one would need to have the proper compositions, and therefore the proper bilinear mappings, being somewhat of an abstraction to analyze multilinear mappings. That would make it a "stronger product", since it allows one to construct the multilinear mappings directly from $U\times V$, because of the universal property.

I don't know if I made myself clear, but, is that right? Is that a suitable understanding of tensor products? Even if it is, I have some remaining concerns. Firstly,  I don't know what should I make out of tensor products from this, since that pretty much just tells why he's defined, and doesn't give an explicit understanding behind it. Furthermore, how does that utterly implies that a tensor is simply an element of the tensor product:
\begin{equation}\bigotimes_{p\ copies}V\ \otimes\ \bigotimes_{q\ copies}V^{*}\end{equation}
Don't really know if I'm making sense, but I'll appreciate some help here.

Oh, and for the sake of simplfying notation, I've used bilinear maps, but it follows exatcly equally for multilinear maps, which is the general definition. That's I've used the word sometimes, since nothing really changes structurally.

Comment: A tensor is something that transforms like a tensor. 

Comment: @CaptainChicky this joke only makes sense in the setting of smooth manifolds. OP is talking about tensor products of vector spaces

Comment: One could define a "tensor" simply to be an element of any tensor product. But in practice the term tensor usually mean an element of a tensor product of p copies of a single vector space $V$ and q copies of its *dual* $V^*$

Comment: 1. What does $|W|^{|U\times V|}$ denote and why is it a vector space?

2. Vector spaces and bilinear maps don't form a category, so you didn't define a functor at all.

3. As ContraKinta points out, the most reasonable thing is to not define ''a tensor'' and instead define ''a tensor over $V$'' as an element of some tensor product space $T^p_q(V)$.

Comment: tensors are like any other machine, they are either a benefit or a hazard, if they are benefit, is not a problem

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz I should've be more expositive, the bars usually define the cardinality of the sets, from which follows that this represents the number of maps from $U\times V$ to $W$. Since my notation covers $\textbf{all}$ maps between those sets, not only bilinear ones, maybe it's a loose way to use it. But anyway, suppose we're talking only about the bilinear ones. It's a set of bilinear mappings, that is, functions linear in both variables, equipped with usual operations; seems natural that this forms a vector space.

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz Which(es) axiom(s) of a category, exactly, does a set of vector spaces $\mathcal{V}\in\text{ob}(\mathcal{C})$ and a set of bilinear maps $\Phi\in\text{Hom}(\mathcal{C})$ wouldn't follow, for some category $\mathcal{C}$?

Comment: Maybe I'm not understandind your proposed construction. I can't even begin to construct a category with vector spaces as objects and bilinear maps as morphisms. E.g., given two vector spaces $V,W$, what would the morphisms $V→W$ be? (Note: I have replaced my previous comment with this one. The other one was almost exactly the same as this one but I thought the opening sentence sounded too rude, so sorry about that).